# Ionic Wait for Local Storage

Tags: ionic-framework, async-await, local-storage

I need to wait for the localStorage to retrieve a value before continuing my function... I read that I have to use "async/await" instructions but none of the examples I found really works.

My Code is

```
  _ajustes.EsPrimeraVez().then (async (promAjuste)=> {
    await console.log('TEST! en el then');
  });
  console.log('TEST! Post');
```

and inside  "ajustes":

```
public EsPrimeraVez() {
   console.log('TEST! entrando en primeravez');
   return this.storage.get('primeravez');
```

but it doesn't wait to the result to continue... is this possible?
Thanks and happy new year to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using prmoise/then syntac if you want to wait to retrieve value from a function. Below code will run sequentially and once function is executed it will assign local storage value to variable 'mystoragevalue'.

```
var mystoragevalue = _ajustes.EsPrimeraVez();
console.log('TEST! Post');
```

and inside "ajustes":

```
public EsPrimeraVez() {
   console.log('TEST! entrando en primeravez');
   return this.storage.get('primeravez');
}
```

Hope this helps...Happy coding...!!!

Comment: I was taught that always return a promise... I didn't know that you can doing it sequencially... you save me! thanks!

Comment: the problem is that mystoragevalue doesn't have the actual value, just the Promise... how do I read the value?

Comment: I already figured out... doing a ".then" on that object... just like it was async...